# Cannot understand behaviour of ifup/ifdown and /etc/init-d/networking

Tags: networking, network-interface, ip, ifconfig, lan

I want to connect an IP camera to my laptop which runs Ubuntu. The set up looks like this:

[image]

Once I have the physical connections, I change my /etc/network/interfaces file from:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

to

```
auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet static
address 169.254.100.1
netmask 255.255.0.0
```

where `enp0s31f6` is the name of my wired interface.

After doing this, I am actually able to connect the camera. However, if I don't after an instant again change the file to:

```
auto enp0s31f6
#iface enp0s31f6 inet static
#address 169.254.100.1
#netmask 255.255.0.0
```

(Notice the comments) the connection with the camera fails again!

Why do you think this is happening?

Comment: Recent releases of Ubuntu use `netplan`.  See https://askubuntu.com/q/1103322/295286 and https://askubuntu.com/q/1029531/295286

Comment: Also think about running a DHCP server for this interface on the computer, to allow the camera to acquire a non-local-link IP. And yes, probably one of the newer replacements for `/etc/network/interfaces` is getting in the way.